# flutter: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode

Tags: android, flutter

I am using   `geolocator: ^6.1.5` to get location on my flutter project.

```
  Future<Position> getDeviceCurrentLocation() async {
    var permission = await requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied ||
        permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // no permission
      return null;
    } else {
      return await getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    }
  }
```

but when i run on my phone and i accept location permission, my app is killed and i got this error on my console:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23743): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.checkForValidRequestCode(FragmentActivity.java:715)
E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startIntentSenderForResult(FragmentActivity.java:687)
E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status.startResolutionForResult(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at com.baseflow.geolocator.location.FusedLocationClient.lambda$startPositionUpdates$3$FusedLocationClient(FusedLocationClient.java:160)
E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at com.baseflow.geolocator.location.-$$Lambda$FusedLocationClient$2YQoY4DnaNIJRZJdAtb1wbssLKw.onFailure(lambda)
E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzl.run(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime(23743):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

flutter doctor:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.51.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Did you enable androidX in android/gradle.properties and set the compileSdkVersion to 30 in the android/app/build.gradle file as specified in geolocator's readme?

Comment: No ,and my compileSdkVersion is 28 .@dumazy